# await mvc4 does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with my code, await key word does not work in asp.net mvc4, I do not know what is the problem but when I wrote it the .net framework did not color it by blue!!

> this is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using workflow.Authorize;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using workflow.DataHolders;
using workflow.Models;
using workflow;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ValidateAndSignUp(ForCompany newCompany)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            company NewCompany = new company();
            TryUpdateModel(NewCompany);
            context.companies.Add(NewCompany);
            int processStatus= context.SaveChanges();
            if (processStatus != 0)
            {
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.To.Add(newCompany.Email);
                message.Subject = "You have created new account";
                message.Body = "Hi, Welcom to HWorkflow website this email is to approve your account and to creat the first user, please click on the link below to approve your account and to creat your first user";
                message.From = new MailAddress("HWorkflowTeam@hworkflow.com");
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = "hworkflowteam",  // replace with valid value
                    Password = "No-access"  // replace with valid value
                };
                var smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = "mail.hworkflow.com";
                smtp.Port = 25;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);

            }
            return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("signUp", newCompany);
        }
    }
```

so please could anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Color it blue? What do you mean? How doesn't it work?

Comment: I got an error that the operator can only be used with asynchronous method, but I do not know why it does not accept it with the  SendMailAsync method!!!

Comment: @AhmNaim: The compiler will give you an error message that tells you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark your method as `async` and to return a `Task<T>`

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ValidateAndSignUp(ForCompany newCompany)
{
    await ...
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works but I do not which answer should I accept you or @Matt

Comment: @AhmNaim Both solutions are correct, Your choice (I was first ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Your Method Signature does not indicate that this is an async / awaitable method.

try

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ValidateAndSignUp(ForCompany newCompany)
....
```

Comment: Jamie beat me to it :-)